# Javascript works when typed directly in template, but not when imported from src file

Tags: javascript, html, flask-bootstrap

This javascript populates a SelectField with a value from a variable (named physical_location). It works when the Javascript is inserted directly in the template like so:

```
<th> Format {{ form.physical_location(class_='form-control physical_location', value=physical_location) }} </th>

<script> var els = document.getElementsByClassName("physical_location");
    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].value = els[i].getAttribute('value');
}
</script>
```

However, when I try to tidy things up and place it in a separate file, it doesn't work as it did previously. For example, I have tried this in the template file:

```
<script src="static/js/populateselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<th> Format {{ form.physical_location(class_='form-control physical_location', value=physical_location) }} </th>
```

And this in populateselect.js:

```
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("physical_location");
    for (i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
        els[i].value = els[i].getAttribute('value');
}
```

EDIT** It's been suggested in the answers that my issue is related to me placing the src above the form in the template. As a result I've amended the template lie so:

```
<th> Physical Location {{ form.physical_location(class_='form-control physical_location', value=physical_location) }} </th>
<script src="static/js/populateselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

However, this hasn't resolved the issue. I must have done something else wrong also(?)

Comment: If you put the script above the DOM elements its supposed to manipulate it won't work unless you wrap your code in a DOMReady event handler. You altered the position between the two samples, it has nothing to do with inline script vs. tag src.

Comment: try to place your script tag below `<th>`

Comment: I've amended my template but the suggestion doesn't seem to have resolved the issue. (see edited post).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two differences between your code samples:

- The script is either inline or from a URL
- The script is before the HTML it tries to access with the DOM or after

You've picked the wrong one of the two to blame for your problem.

[You can't access DOM elements before they exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element).

Comment: I've amended my template but the suggestion doesn't seem to have resolved the issue.